# link a row in a table when any table data selected with php only

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, href

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    echo'<tr input type="hidden" name="hide" id="ord" value=' . $order_number . ' href="form3.php?action&veh_sel='.$row['vehicle_id_pk'].'">';
    echo'<td>'.$row['vehicle_id_pk'].'</td>';
    echo "<td>content2</td>";
    echo'<td>content3</td>';
    echo'</a></tr>';
    }
```

What I am trying to achieve is that when a user clicks on any of the TD content in each row, it passes the value of vehicle_id_pk as well as the hidden info (similar to ).

is this possible using pure php? or can i wrap the whole thing in a  tags?

p.s - the database & query side of it works fine, and I can also get a form tag to work in a specific cell, just haveing trouble with selecting the whole row as the "button"

Comment: You definitely cannot do this with your current code as it's laden with errors. Further, your HTML markup will cause display errors in it's current state. Lastly, you can both $_GET and $_POST to a php script at the same time, but not using your current method.

Comment: ive tidied the code up. i know the code i posted up there doesnt work and has errors, but ive put it that way to show what id like to achieve. which is pass a hidden value and a row value when somebody selects a row.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why this needs to be done in php alone? This type of task is a nice opportunity to use some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Well this code is tested with a **tr** tag and you need to use at least jQuery. I don't know if it's possible with only php.

HTML

```
 echo'<td id="'.$row['vehicle_id_pk'].'" class="edit_td">'.$row['vehicle_id_pk'].'</td>';
```

Jquery

```
$(".edit_td").click(function()
{
    //Getting the value from id **tr**, in this case you could try with .edit_td class for example
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#ord").val(id);        
});
```

I've use this code with a **tr** tag, when someone click on a specific **tr** tag, the jquery click gets the id value from that **tr** (in your case you could try with **td**). 
Then you are assigning the id value to the input with the id "ord". As your code is a little incomplete as you comment, maybe this could help you start with something.